# Speed of propagation of the condition of constant phase

Tags: thermodynamics, waves

My textbook, *Optics, Fifth Edition*, by Hecht, says the following in a section on **phase and phase velocity**:

> The phase of a disturbance such as $\psi(x, t)$ given by Eq. (2.28) is
>
> $$\varphi(x, t) = (kx - \omega t + \epsilon)$$
>
> and is obviously a function fo $x$ and $y$. In fact, the partial derivative of $\varphi$ with respect to $t$, holding $x$ constant, is the *rate-of-change of phase with time*, or
>
> $$\left| \left( \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} \right)_x \right| = \omega \tag{2.30}$$
>
> The rate-of-change of phase at any fixed location is the angular frequency of the wave, the rate at which a point on the rope in Fig. 2.12 oscillates up and down. That point must go through the same number of cycles as the wave. For each cycle, $\varphi$ change by $2\pi$. The quantity $\omega$ is the number of radians the phase sweeps through per second. The quantity $k$ is the number of radians the phase sweeps through per meter.
>
> Similarly, the *rate-of-change of phase with distance*, holding $t$ constant, is
>
> $$\left| \left( \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \right)_t \right| = k \tag{2.31}$$
>
> These two expressions should bring to mind an equation from the theory of partial derivatives, one used frequently in Thermodynamics, namely,
>
> $$\left( \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)_\varphi = \dfrac{-(\partial \varphi / \partial t)_x}{(\partial \varphi / \partial x)_t} \tag{2.32}$$
>
> The term on the left represents the *speed of propagation of the condition of constant phase*. Imagine a harmonic wave and choose any point on the profile, for example, a crest of the wave. As the wave moves through space, the displacement $y$ of the crest remains fixed. Since the only variable in the harmonic wavefunction is the phase, it too must be constant for that moving point. That is, the phase is fixed at such a value as to yield the constant $y$ corresponding to the chosen point. The point moves along with the profile at the speed $v$, and so too does the condition of constant phase.

I am not familiar with (2.32). The author takes the time to explain the left-hand, but does not explain how this result comes about. And my searches of "speed of propagation of the condition of constant phase thermodynamics" do not seem to yield any relevant results. Therefore, I was wondering if people could please take the time to explain how (2.32) is derived.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe the author has made use of the following identity : [Triple Product Identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule). SE has many answers related to proving this relation ([PhySE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392770/proof-on-showing-if-fx-y-z-0-then-product-of-partial-derivatives-evaluated-at)).

Comment: @AjayMohan Ahh, this looks to be it! Thanks!